# Java Timer and scheduleAtFixedRate + System Suspend

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, scheduled-tasks, sleep

I am working on a Java program and using `Timer` objects to run tasks every few minutes or hours. This works fine in normal operations, but I am running into a problem with "Sleep mode" on Mac (maybe on other OSes, but I haven't tried yet).

Consider this code sample:

```
//Setup the timer to fire the ping worker (every 3 minutes)
_PingTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            Program.PingThread = new PingWorker(Settings.Username, Settings.UserHash, true, true);
            Program.PingThread.CheckOpenPort = true;
            Program.SwingExecutor.execute(Program.PingThread);
        }
    }, 0, 180000);
```

In normal operation this would fire every 3 minutes with enough accuracy (I'm not concerned about the exact second or anything). The problem with this is after sleeping the computer for a few hours or so it seems to just BLAST the system with backlogged timer requests.

It seems to be running all of the missed timer hits during sleep at once trying to make up for lost time.

Is there a way i can prevent this? I tried using `synchronized` and some other thread techniques, but this only ensures that they aren't all running at the same time. They still continue to run one after another until the backlog is passed.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: *can't help* - is it just with a mac, or sleeping in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29)? It clearly states the following:

> In fixed-rate execution, each
>   execution is scheduled relative to the
>   scheduled execution time of the
>   initial execution. If an execution is
>   delayed for any reason (such as
>   garbage collection or other background
>   activity), two or more executions will
>   occur in rapid succession to "catch
>   up." In the long run, the frequency of
>   execution will be exactly the
>   reciprocal of the specified period
>   (assuming the system clock underlying
>   Object.wait(long) is accurate).

This is one reason why you should consider using a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637618/how-to-reschedule-a-task-using-a-scheduledexecutorservice) may also prove useful.

Comment: Apparently I missed this important note! Thanks for the advice about `ScheduledExecutorService`. I'm looking into this, I'll put it through the paces tonight.

Comment: Well, I gave this a whirl and it seemed to have the same results. However I just realized I was using `scheduleAtFixedRate` rather than `scheduleWithFixedDelay`. I am trying it again with the latter.

Comment: `scheduleWithFixedDelay` was the ticket! Everything seems to be in order now. Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you so much! This happens on Windows as well. For a while we wondered why CPU usage shot up when waking up from hibernation, until we realized that scheduleWithFixedDelay floods your CPU with threads.

Answer (score 2):

Use `schedule` instead of `scheduleAtFixedRate`.

Comment: `schedule` does not re-queue itself does it?