# Interrrupt-able ScheduledExecutorService in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Currently, I am designing a stock market app with the following requirement

- 1) Scan stock price repeatedly, with a fixed sleep time.
- 2) Able to interrupt the sleep any-time. This is because when user adds a new stock, we need to wake up from sleep, and scan immediately.

Previously, I'm using bare bone `Thread`, to full-fill the above 2 requirements.

```
private class StockMonitor extends Thread { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();

        while (thisThread == thread) {

            // Fetch stock prices...

            try {
                Thread.sleep(MIN_DELAY);
            } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException exp) {
                if (false == refreshed()) {
                    /* Exit the primary fail safe loop. */
                    thread = null;                            
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void refresh() {        
        isRefresh = true;
        interrupt();
    }

    private synchronized boolean refreshed() {
        if (isRefresh) {
            isRefresh = false;
            // Interrupted status of the thread is cleared.
            interrupted();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I want to perform requirement (2), I will call `refresh`. Thread will be waked up, and perform job immediately.

However, I feel it is difficult to maintain such bare bone Thread code, and can make mistake easily.

I prefer to use `ScheduledExecutorService`. However, it lack of ability for me to wake up the Thread from sleeping state, and perform job immediately.

I was wondering, is there any classes in Android, which enables me to perform periodically task as in `ScheduledExecutorService`? Yet has the ability to wake up the Thread from sleeping state, and perform job immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution with `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. To cancel existing tasks, issue `future.cancel()` on Future object returned from `scheduleAtFixedRate()`. Then call `scheduleAtFixedRate()` again with `initial delay` set to 0.

```
class HiTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Say Hi!");
    } 
}

// periodically execute task in every 100 ms, without initial delay time

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

long initialDelay = 0;
long period = 100;

ScheduledFuture<?> future1 = exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new HiTask(), initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


// to trigger task execution immediately

boolean success = future.cancel(true);    // mayInterruptIfRunning = true: interrupt thread even task has already started

ScheduledFuture<?> future2 = exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new HiTask(), initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Options you have with `ScheduledExecutorService`:

- `submit()` the same task again in the moment you need the data to be refreshed. If will be immediately executed (and only once). Possible drawback: If this happens very close to a scheduled execution, you have two scans with very little time in between.
- `cancel()` the Tasks in the moment you need the data to be refreshed, `submit()` it once for immediate execution and and `schedule()` for repeated execution.

Be aware that any exceptions that occur in the task that are unhandled cancel future executions. How to solve that is answered in [How to reschedule a task using a ScheduledExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637618/how-to-reschedule-a-task-using-a-scheduledexecutorservice).

`ExecutorService` is not persistent (i.e. does not survive device reboot). I don't know if that's a problem for you. If it is there are libraries specialized on background task execution on Android:

- [smart-scheduler-android](https://github.com/hypertrack/smart-scheduler-android)
- [android-priority-jobqueue](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue)
- [android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)

You would have to apply the same workarounds mentioned above.